Help with Nav2 Costmap Plugin for Multiple Robots
I'm working on a Nav2 costmap plugin to integrate sensor information from three mobile robots. The goal is for obstacles detected by one robot to appear in the global costmap of all robots, even if some cannot see them.
I’ve tried subscribing to the three LaserScan topics, but I haven’t been able to display any information on the costmap. I also reviewed the code for the Nav2 obstacle layer plugin but found it difficult to understand.
Could anyone provide guidance on how to mark obstacles in the costmap and properly subscribe to LaserScan topics for multiple robots?
Thank you!

I've made some progress, but it's not fully working yet.
Following @ivrolan's tips, I successfully subscribed to the LaserScan topic from one robot and shared it with another via the costmap. However, I’m facing an issue: the shared costmap shifts and rotates when one of the robots moves, rather than staying fixed to the map frame.
I've shared my code below for reference.
.cpp file
#include "nav2_multi_robot_costmap_plugin/shared_sensor_data_layer.hpp"
#include <pluginlib/class_list_macros.hpp>
#include <nav2_costmap_2d/costmap_layer.hpp>
#include <tf2_geometry_msgs/tf2_geometry_msgs.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/msg/pose_stamped.hpp>
#include "nav2_costmap_2d/costmap_math.hpp"
#include "nav2_costmap_2d/costmap_2d.hpp"
#include "geometry_msgs/msg/pose_array.hpp"
#include "sensor_msgs/point_cloud2_iterator.hpp"

#include <vector>


namespace nav2_multi_robot_costmap_plugin
{

SharedSensorData::SharedSensorData()
{
}

void SharedSensorData::onInitialize()
{
   declareParameter("scan_topic", rclcpp::ParameterValue(""));
   declareParameter("enabled", rclcpp::ParameterValue(true));
    // Get the node handle from the costmap
    auto node = node_.lock();
    if (!node) 
    {
        throw std::runtime_error{"Failed to lock node"};
    }

    // Set up the global frame and transformation tolerance
    global_frame_ = layered_costmap_->getGlobalFrameID();
  
    // Get the laser scan topic name from parameters
    node->get_parameter(name_ + "." + "scan_topic", scan_topic_);
    node->get_parameter(name_ + "." + "enabled", enabled_);

    // Subscribe to the LaserScan topic
    auto qos = rclcpp::SensorDataQoS();
    robot_scan_sub = node->create_subscription<sensor_msgs::msg::LaserScan>(
    scan_topic_, qos,
    std::bind(&SharedSensorData::laserScanCallback, this, std::placeholders::_1));
}

void SharedSensorData::laserScanCallback(const sensor_msgs::msg::LaserScan::SharedPtr scan)
{
  cloud.header = scan->header;
  laserscan = scan;

  projector_.transformLaserScanToPointCloud(scan->header.frame_id, *scan, cloud, *tf_);
}
//updateBounds taken from Nav2 Costmap Plugin tutorial
void SharedSensorData::updateBounds(
  double robot_x, double robot_y, double robot_yaw, double * min_x,
  double * min_y, double * max_x, double * max_y)
{
  if(!enabled_)
  {
    return;
  }
  if (need_recalculation_) {
    last_min_x_ = *min_x;
    last_min_y_ = *min_y;
    last_max_x_ = *max_x;
    last_max_y_ = *max_y;
    // For some reason when I make these -<double>::max() it does not
    // work with Costmap2D::worldToMapEnforceBounds(), so I'm using
    // -<float>::max() instead.
    *min_x = -std::numeric_limits<float>::max();
    *min_y = -std::numeric_limits<float>::max();
    *max_x = std::numeric_limits<float>::max();
    *max_y = std::numeric_limits<float>::max();
    need_recalculation_ = false;
  } else {
    double tmp_min_x = last_min_x_;
    double tmp_min_y = last_min_y_;
    double tmp_max_x = last_max_x_;
    double tmp_max_y = last_max_y_;
    last_min_x_ = *min_x;
    last_min_y_ = *min_y;
    last_max_x_ = *max_x;
    last_max_y_ = *max_y;
    *min_x = std::min(tmp_min_x, *min_x);
    *min_y = std::min(tmp_min_y, *min_y);
    *max_x = std::max(tmp_max_x, *max_x);
    *max_y = std::max(tmp_max_y, *max_y);
  }
}
    
void SharedSensorData::updateCosts(nav2_costmap_2d::Costmap2D &master_grid, int min_i, int min_j, int max_i, int max_j)
{
  sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstIterator<float> iter_x(cloud, "x");
  sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstIterator<float> iter_y(cloud, "y");
  for (; iter_x != iter_x.end(); ++iter_x, ++iter_y)
  {
    double point_x = *iter_x, point_y = *iter_y;
    
    unsigned int mx, my;
      if (worldToMap(point_x, point_y, mx, my)) {
        master_grid.setCost(mx, my, nav2_costmap_2d::LETHAL_OBSTACLE);
      }
  }
}

 
} // namespace nav2_multi_robot_costmap_plugin

// This is the macro allowing a nav2_multi_robot_costmap_plugin::SharedSensorData class
// to be registered in order to be dynamically loadable of base type nav2_costmap_2d::Layer.
// Usually places in the end of cpp-file where the loadable class written.
#include "pluginlib/class_list_macros.hpp"
PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS(nav2_multi_robot_costmap_plugin::SharedSensorData, nav2_costmap_2d::Layer)

.hpp file
#ifndef SHARED_SENSOR_DATA_LAYER_HPP_
#define SHARED_SENSOR_DATA_LAYER_HPP_

#include <nav2_costmap_2d/layer.hpp>
#include <nav2_costmap_2d/costmap_layer.hpp>
#include <nav2_costmap_2d/layered_costmap.hpp>
#include "laser_geometry/laser_geometry.hpp"
#include <sensor_msgs/msg/laser_scan.hpp>
#include "sensor_msgs/msg/point_cloud2.hpp"
#include <geometry_msgs/msg/pose_with_covariance_stamped.hpp>
#include <tf2_ros/transform_listener.h>
#include <tf2_ros/buffer.h>
#include "nav2_costmap_2d/footprint.hpp"


namespace nav2_multi_robot_costmap_plugin
{



class SharedSensorData : public nav2_costmap_2d::CostmapLayer
{
public:
    SharedSensorData();
    virtual ~SharedSensorData() override = default;

    virtual void onInitialize() override;
    virtual void updateBounds(double robot_x, double robot_y, double robot_yaw, double *min_x, double *min_y, double *max_x, double *max_y) override;
    virtual void updateCosts(nav2_costmap_2d::Costmap2D &master_grid, int min_i, int min_j, int max_i, int max_j) override;
    virtual void reset()    
    {
      return;
    }
    virtual bool isClearable() {return false;}
private:
    // Callback function for the LaserScan topic
    void laserScanCallback(const sensor_msgs::msg::LaserScan::SharedPtr scan);

    rclcpp::Subscription<sensor_msgs::msg::LaserScan>::SharedPtr robot_scan_sub;
   
    // Store scan data for later use
    sensor_msgs::msg::LaserScan::SharedPtr laserscan;
    sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2 cloud;

    laser_geometry::LaserProjection projector_;
 
    // Topic name for the laser scan
    std::string scan_topic_;

    // Global frame and tolerance for transforming poses
    std::string global_frame_;
    bool enabled_;
    double last_min_x_, last_min_y_, last_max_x_, last_max_y_;
};

}  // namespace nav2_multi_robot_costmap_plugin

#endif  // SHARED_SENSOR_DATA_LAYER_HPP_


Could you point out more specifically where you are struggling to get your plugin to work?
I also had a bit of trouble getting my plugin to work as I intended and thankfully, I could use as help the tutorial of the Costmap plugin of Nav2 and some other examples like the Spatio Temporal Voxel Layer.
In the tutorial, the plugin they write inherits from nav2_costmap_2d::Layer while SPTVL is a nav2_costmap_2d::CostmapLayer that inherits from both Layer and Costmap2D to provide more operations on how to update the area of the costmap (you can take a look to the definitions in the Nav2 repo). Basically, the plugin will save information based on the topics and will update the costmap when its method updateCosts() is called. My personal advice would be to first test a dummy plugin that just writes dummy information on the costmap and then trace if this is successful or not. If it works, add complexity by including information from the topics. If this works, then also try to clear information if the lasers stop seeing obstacles at a certain point...
Regarding your application, you could write one plugin to subscribe to these 3 LaserScan topics and you could also write one plugin that only subscribes to one topic and add 3 of these. In the configuration file, you can add the 3 plugins (as long as they don't erase information from each other) and have a more flexible configuration. That could more convenient or not depending on your case, so it is up to you!

Thank you for your response!
I’ve set up subscribers for all three LaserScans in the plugin, but I’m having trouble marking cells as occupied when iterating over ranges and angles. I'll follow your advice to implement it step-by-step, starting with dummy data.

Good luck! Let us know how it goes and if you're still stuck on something specific do not hesitate to post!
